# Running a jmeter test via Blazemeter Taurus and Jenkins

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, taurus

I am having issues with  my jmeter test.

I am using Blazemeter Taurus (bzt command) to run it, and I run it as a Jenkins job.
My issue is:
I created user defined values, which I set as Jmeter properties so I can pass them params from the command line:
[example for a property I set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJNOf.png)

The issue occurs when I pass a number:
bzt  -o modules.jmeter.properties.profileId=413 -o modules.jmeter.properties.lab=8050

these are parsed as 8050.0 and 413.0
Because the "lab" param is embeded in a url, it breaks the url.

When running this via command line with the jmeter command, this works fine.

I tried working around this with a bean shell sampler that does the following:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(vars.get(${lab}));
String raw = String.ValueOf(a);
String processed = raw.substring(0,5);    


vars.putObject("lab" ,new String(processed));
props.put("lab", lab);
log.info("this is the new " + ${lab});
```

but this fails. 
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. In regards to Taurus issue - report it via [Taurus support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codename-taurus)
2. In regards to Beanshell workaround - your code is not very correct, you need to amend it as follows:

   ```
   int lab = (int)Double.parseDouble(props.get("lab"));
   int profileId = (int)Double.parseDouble(props.get("profileId"));

   props.put("lab", String.valueOf(lab));
   props.put("profileId", String.valueOf("profileId"));

   log.info("lab=" + lab);
   log.info("profileId=" + profileId);
   ```

as stuff passed via `-o modules.jmeter.properties` should be accessed via `props` shorthand, not `vars`

Demo:

[image: Beanshell props manipulation Demo]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on using JMeter and Java API from Beanshell test elements in your JMeter test.

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri T. I will check this out next week and see if the issue is resolved. I will update.